# Create a Rank based on the Frame Played and Won

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been trying to create a Rank based on the Frame played and Won. All i got is the Rank formula from the Google.

```
=RANK(D2,$D$2:$D$18)
```

But i want a fair Ranks if player has played 1 frame and won 1 then its ranks will be next from the player who played 3 frames and won 3.

I have attached a picture with Ranks Result and The Result I want.

Your help will be appreciated.

[[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lpgxH.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, try the next code. In order to work well, the range should be sorted descending, by column "D:D" (like in your picture sample) and the percentages should be calculated without decimals (using Round). As it looks in your picture (but not by `Decrease decimal` format...):

```
Sub specRank()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rng As Range, arr, arrF, arrFin
   
   Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the necessary sheet
   lastR = sh.Range("B" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in column B:B
   
   Set rng = sh.Range("B2:D" & lastR)
   
   With Application
      'place the two columns value concatenation in an array:
      arr = .Transpose(Evaluate(rng.Columns(3).Address & "&" & rng.Columns(1).Address))
      'obtain the unique values array:
      arrF = .Index(arr, 1, Filter(.IfError(.match(.Transpose(.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & _
                    UBound(arr) + 1 & ")")), .match(arr, arr, 0), 0), "|"), "|", False))
      arrFin = .match(arr, arrF, 0)   'match the above arrays to obtain the result array
  End With
  'drop the array content in the necessary column:
  sh.Range("E2").Resize(UBound(arrFin), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(arrFin)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks works perfect

Answer (score 0):

If you use ***Excel-365*** then could try-

```
=XMATCH(D2&B2,UNIQUE($D$2:$D$18&$B$2:$B$18),0)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you but i have excel 2016. @Harun24HR

Comment: I have changed the picture with result can you please look into this @Harun24HR

Comment: Its hard to rank it on older version. You need legacy array function. I will try to post when will get free.

Comment: I will appreciate your help